# Best way to use APNS with a login validated app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to implement push notifications for an app does works under a valid user and password. This authentication is handled using some web services on the server side now and was wondering which would be the best way to send push notifications for such app, as it's possible that the user is not logged in at the app, then he/she shouldn't be able to see the push notification. The same applies when another user has logged in on the same device.

Haven't found much information on this but think the best would be that the app sends status information(login, logout) to the server, so the server, before sending a push notification, checks if a user is logged in at the app, and which user is logged in. This could have some issues as it could happen that the app crashes or the mobile goes off, and the app is not able to send a logout status to the server, which would lead to push notifications for a not logged-in device. Probably there are other issues with this approach.

Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct. You can certainly tell the server when you have logged in/out, but there is always a chance that the login state can become unsynchronized between the device and the server. You could implement the desired functionality while the app is running by maintaining a persistent connection to the server and only sending a push notification while the connection exists; if the app crashes or is exited the connection would break and push notifications would stop. This won't help if you want to receive notifications when the app is exited or backgrounded, however.